# C# Generar un codigo que genere numeros aleatorios y que los guarde en una lista

Tags: c#

Antes de nada, la idea del **codigo** es hacer lo del titulo y tambien que los **numeros** generados se sumen ( todos), que me diga que numeros son parejos i quales son imparejos.El Problema de esto es que me he quedado estancado haciendo solo los **numeros generados** i creando la **lista**, ya llevo **media hora y no avanzo**. Esto es lo que tengo de codigo:

```
ArrayList numeros2 = new ArrayList();
            Random r= new Random ();
 
            for (int i=0;i<500;i++){
 
                
                Console.WriteLine(r.Next ());
 
            }
 
            Console.ReadLine ();
```

Comment: He buscado y tal pero solo encuentro lo de guardar los numeros aleatorios en otro lenguajes como java o python pero claro a mi me interesa que sea en c#

Comment: Pues ahí tienes la generación del siguiente, te queda usar un método del ArrayList que te permite añadir esos nuevos elementos. Después, alguna estructura que te permita recorrerlo e irlos sumando. Lo de parejos o imparejos, qué es eso?

Comment: @Alfabravo lo de parejos e imparejos es que dentro de los números aleatorios que he generado me diga cuáles son iguales y cuáles no .

Comment: @Alfabravo El problema es que no se casi nada sobre los ArrayList , es que el profe de programacion que tengo no explica nada

Comment: Siempre hay que comenzar por la [documentación oficial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-7.0) y no depender de que el profe te dé todo :)

Comment: El profe, nunca te va a explicar nada.. para eso, esta lo que te dicen arriba, la documentacion!!! es tu mejor aliada.. lee y aprende.. y si tenes dudas en particular, veni y decinos, y con gusto te vamos a ayudar.. pero no vamoa a hacerte el ejercicio...

Comment: Me temo que no entiendo mucho la documentacion de Microsoft ( ten en cuenta que no tengo ni 40 horas de experiencia programando en c#), igualmente la he mirado pero no encuentro nada de guardar numeros generados aleatoriamente en una ArrayList

Comment: @gbianchi Yo tema documentacion miro https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_arrays.php que me es mas facil , claro he mirado ahi lo de guardar numeros generados aleatoriamente pero no hay nada para lo mio. Bueno intentare hacer otro ejercicio para no perder demasiado tiempo con este

Comment: @Alfabravo se podria hacer con una lista normal entonces de con una ArrayList ?

Comment: Yo creo que tengo aún menos horas de C#. Igual, lo importante es que entiendas los conceptos y así navegar cualquier documentación va a ser fácil. Si cambias la estructura de datos, sólo cambias la forma de guardar y leer los datos (y bueh, cambia la eficiencia y rapidez con la que corre tu programa, etc... después verás de qué va eso).  Revisa: a) cómo guardar algo en una variable, b) cómo guardar algo como elemento de un ArrayList (eso está en el enlace que te di!), c) cómo recorrer un ArrayList, d) cómo sumar dos valores y guardar el resultado en una variable. Ahí está tu ejercicio. Ánimo!

Comment: La pregunta es, porque estas leyendo la documentacion de cualquier lado, menos de donde corresponde? arraylist no es lo mismo que array.. uno es un objeto que implementa un array, el otro es un array comun... Acostumbrate a leer la documentacion oficial.. lo que estas buscando, no es como guardar numeros aleatorios en un array (de ahi tu problema) estas buscando como guardar CUALQUIER elemento en un array list... y ahi si, vas a encontrar la informacion que queres.. lo otro, es tu ejercicio...

Comment: @gbianchi Bueni al final me ha salido ( no se como la verdad) he mirado la documentacion oficial pero solo habia encontrado una cosilla de nada, al final lo que he hecho ha sido pillar esa pequeña informacion que he conseguido y buscar mas informacion a traves de otras pagina y por ultimo he reciclado codigo( y milagrosamente a funcionado xd)

Comment: Mira esto, te será útil https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections

Comment: @Mateo Ya lo he conseguido hacer pero igualmente gracias por pasar la documentacion

Answer (score 0):

Te envío exactamente lo que buscas poniendo un comentario sobre como funciona cada proceso realizado, espero te sea de gran ayuda.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

        // Solicita cuantos números se desea
        Console.WriteLine("Digite cuantos números desea en la lista: ");
        int CantidadNumero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        // Rango incial para buscar los números
        Console.WriteLine("Digite el rango inicial: ");
        int RangoInicial = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        // Rango final para buscar los números
        Console.WriteLine("Digite el rango final: ");
        int RangoFinal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 


        List<int> ListaGenerados = new List<int>();
        Random random = new Random();

        // Obtener cada número aleatorio y guardarlo en la lista según la cantidad digitada al inicio
        for (int i = 0; i < CantidadNumero; i++)
        {
            int NumeroNuevo = random.Next(RangoInicial, RangoFinal);

            ListaGenerados.Add(NumeroNuevo);
        }
        
        // Sumar Todos los numeros de la lista
        int TotalLista = ListaGenerados.Sum();
        
        // Verficar numeros Pares e Impares
        int TotalPares = 0;
        int TotalImpares = 0;

        foreach (var Numero in ListaGenerados)
        {
            if (Numero % 2 == 0)
            {
                TotalPares = TotalPares + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                TotalImpares = TotalImpares + 1;
            }

        }


        Console.WriteLine("Lista de Números");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", ListaGenerados));
        Console.WriteLine("Operaciones");
        Console.WriteLine("La Suma Total de los Numeros es {0}, El Total de Numeros Pares es {1} y el Total de Impares es {2}",TotalLista,TotalPares,TotalImpares);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [answer], en especial la sección _contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: la respuesta no esta mal... pero... tiene 2 cosas que no son del ejercicio original... se usa ArrayList (no List, son cosas diferentes) y ademas usa LINQ, sin siquiera estar aclarado...